# npm still installing packages to '/usr/local/Cellar/node/...' even though I've uninstalled Homebrew's version of node

Tags: node.js, installation, gruntjs, npm, homebrew

It's been a long night. Originally I had node installed from the package on https://nodejs.org/. However, for some reason (I can't remember why now!), I decided to try uninstalling this and then installing node through Homebrew.

Everything seemed to go fine. I then ran the following:

```
$ npm install grunt -g
$ npm install grunt-cli -g
```

But then when I tried running any of my Grunt tasks I get the following:

```
$ cd /some/project/that/used/grunt
$ grunt
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

I tried uninstalling the Homebrew version of node:

```
$ brew uninstall node
```

I then installed the nodejs.org package again. However when I try to install an npm package it ends up back in the `/usr/local/Cellar/node/...` directory:

```
$ sudo npm install grunt -g
Password:
grunt@0.4.5 /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.2_1/libexec/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt
├── which@1.0.9
...
```

I also found https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22408 and tried the symlink:

```
$ ln -sf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm
```

No luck. How can I get npm to stop installing packages in `/usr/local/Cellar/...` and get Grunt running again? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

This seemed to work. I found the following in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc`:

```
prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.2_1/libexec/npm
```

I removed this line and re-installed the `grunt` and `grunt-cli` packages. It works now.

Comment: OMG! That is a nice little present left around by Brew. Frustrating!!!! Took me a while to find your SO answer. Thanks @robert!